# How to send large/multi-part JSON object without changing maxJsonLength?

Tags: c#, ajax, json, webmethod, windows-server

In my current C# web application I request a JSON object from a WebMethod, this JSON object exceeds the maximumJSONLength. And results in:

> InvalidOperationException: The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

My current solution has been to raise the `maxJsonlength` (in the Web.config) above the JSON length of the object, but now that I am migrating my application over to Windows Server (Which does not seem to support this override). Is there a way to send the JSON object through an ajax POST in parts? If so what is the best solution, I have searched for a way to send the data in multiple parts but there is no clear solution.

Comment: The only way I know of is to change the actual API - e.g. add an "has more" (aka "offset") key that the client can use to request additional results for the same source query.

Comment: Just thinking outside the box here but you could of downloaded it as JSON file and then parsed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution that works with out editing the maxJsonLength, but it allows maxJsonLength to be modified in Windows Server.

Adding the following to my web.config allowed me to then edit the maxJsonLength.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions"         type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
            <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  ... 
</configuration>
```

I hope this helps anyone else coming a similar problem.